# Finding number of distinct walks between two vertices in a graph using Matrix Multiplication

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, triangles, adjacency-matrix

Say, we have a graph G represented by an adjacency matrix A.

[image: Graph G]

```
Adjacency Matrix A

A = 0 1 1 0
    1 0 1 1
    1 1 0 1
    0 1 1 0
```

It is said that `A^n[i][j]` equals the
number of distinct walks of length [![n][2]][2] which start at vertex `i` and end at vertex `j`

```
A^n = A*A*A...n times
```

**Testing for n = 2**

```
A^2 = 2 1 1 2
      1 3 2 1
      1 2 3 1
      2 1 1 2
```

This says that, the number of paths of length 2, between vertex 0 and 0 is 2, which is indeed correct. The paths are `0-1-0` and `0-2-0`

**Testing for n = 3**

```
 A^3 =  2 5 5 2
        5 4 5 2
        5 5 4 5
        2 5 5 2
```

This says that, the number of paths of length 3, between vertex 0 and 1 is 5. Are these paths `0-0-2-1`, `0-1-2-1`, `0-1-3-1`,`0-2-0-1`, `0-2-1-1` and `0-2-3-1'

I would like to know the idea behind this method, and how it's working.

Comment: You can't count 0-0-2-1 as a path of length 3 from 0 to 1, because there is no adjacency between 0 and 0 in the given graph. So you are left with the predicted 5 paths.

Comment: You may have missed `0-1-0-1` but wrongly included `0-0-2-1`

Comment: Consider a sequence $\gamma=(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, then $\gamma$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ if and only if $x_0=x$, $x_n=y$ and $A(\gamma)=1$, where $$A(\gamma)=\prod_{k=1}^nA(x_{k-1},x_k)$$ otherwise, $A(\gamma)=0$. Now, $$A^n(x,y)=\sum_\gamma A(\gamma)$$ where the sum is over every sequence $\gamma=(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that $x_0=x$ and $x_n=y$, qed.

Comment: You also  can't use 0-2-1-1. (I misspoke in earlier comment, since I didn't spot this invalid one.) If we throw in the 0-1-0-1 Henry mentions it looks like 5 in all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the matrix multiplication formula for an individual entry:

$${A^n}_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^v (A^{n-1})_{ik}A_{kj} $$

This translates into something like number paths from $i$ to $j$ is the sum of paths $i$ to $k$ and $k$ to $j$.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.  In the formula above however, isn't it 
 Anij=∑k=1v(An−1)ik . A^n-1kj ? Basically the previous matrix's A[i][k] and A[k][j] are mulitplied  and summed over all k, to get the current matrix. Isn't it?

Comment: This is the multiplication $A^{n-1}*A$, so for the second part you only need $A$. The $A^{n-1}$ is there to show that you should really use an induction argument for the higher powers.